# What are examples of group 14 elements forming dπ - pπ bonding?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, bond

While studying the Group 14 elements, I came across the anomalous behaviour of carbon. In that there was a point:

> Carbon forms only p$\pi$-p$\pi$ type bonding while other elements in the group form p$\pi$-p$\pi$, as well as d$\pi$-p$\pi$ type bonding.

I am searching for molecules in which  group 14 elements form d$\pi$-p$\pi$ bonds.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transition_metal_carbene_complex || However, I would like to see the context. It is common to older textbooks to mention d-orbital involvement for 3+ rows for p-block, while modern quantum chemistry calculations show that this involvements is limited even if present.

Answer (score -1):

For $d\pi-p\pi$ bonding we need to consider other elements of group 14 except $\ce{C}$. (i.e, $\ce{Si, Ge ,Sn}$ etc.) which have got a vacant $d$ orbital of proper symmetry and energy to come into play bonding with attached group  having lone pair of electron in p orbital of comparable energy.
    For example $\ce{SiF4}$. $\ce{GeCl4}$ etc.
In tetrahedral geometry the orientation of vacant  d orbital of the central atom (dxy. dyz,dxz) may overlap with filled p orbital of the ligating atom  and hence $d\pi -p\pi$ bonding is possible.

Comment: $\ce{SiF4}$ is tetrahedral, there's no $\pi$ overlap between Si 3d and F 2p? correct me if I'm wrong. Imo a better example is $\ce{N(SiH3)3}$.